# Why can't you increment/decrement a variable twice in the same expression?

Tags: c, compiler-errors

When I try to compile this code

```
int main() {
    int i = 0;
    ++(++i);
}
```

I get this error message.

> ```
> test.c:3:5: error: lvalue required as increment operand
>      ++(++i);
>      ^
> ```

What is the error message saying? Is this something that gets picked up by the parser, or is it only discovered during semantic analysis?

Comment: Why would you want to? `++` is a special operator for incrementing by 1. For all other values you have `+=`.

Comment: I'm writing a parser for C and wanted to know the source of the error. It seems to me that this is syntactically correct, so the parser shouldn't have a problem with it.

Comment: This makes sense, because trying to compile `i+++++k` gives the same error, meaning that it was parsed as `((i++)++)+k` and not `(i++)+(++k)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`++i` will give an rvalue<sup>**1**</sup> after the evaluation and you can't apply `++` on an rvalue.

§6.5.3.1 (p1):

> **The operand of the prefix increment or decrement operator** shall have atomic, qualified, or unqualified real or pointer type, and **shall be a modifiable lvalue**.

---

<sub>1. What is sometimes called "rvalue" is in this International Standard described as the "value of an expression". - §6.3.2.1 footnote 64).</sub>

Answer (score 3):

A lvalue is a value you can write to / assign to.

You can apply `++` to `i` (`i` is modified) but you cannot apply `++` to the result of the previous `++` operator. I wouldn't have any effect anyway.

Aside: C++ allows that (probably because `++` operator returns a non-const reference on the modified value)

Answer (score 2):

The issue that the (++i) returns new integer value, and please note ++ operation needs some variable for assignment, not a value (you are trying to increment an integer not a variable), so you can use this instead :

```
i += 2;
```

or

```
i = i + 2;
```